# isocalendar giving me some wrong week number

Tags: python-3.x, date, week-number

Here's my dataframe :

[image: df]

And here's my code :

```
week_number= []

for date in df['date']:
    a_date = date
    print(a_date)
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(a_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    print(dt)
    number = dt.isocalendar()[1]
    print(number)
    week_number.append(number)
```

And here's the output :

```
2019-11-14
2019-11-14 00:00:00
46

2019-12-17
2019-12-17 00:00:00
51

2019-12-07
2019-12-07 00:00:00
49

2019-12-14
2019-12-14 00:00:00
50

2019-12-30
2019-12-30 00:00:00
1
```

As you can see, the last one give me 1, why did I do wrong ?

Comment: It is not wrong. It is the first week of 2020 (which may have some days in 2019). This is by definition of ISO week. So careful, if you use ISO week, use ISO-week year, and not standard year, or you get bugs. -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date has nice table with examples on new year periods)

Comment: Oooow I see, so for calculating CA by week it's all good ?

Comment: I do not know what it is CA. But possibly you need delta times (then transforming them in week)? but i do not know that is CA, so...

Comment: Sorry, it was in french, I mean turnover, my bad.